# How to solve exceptions that are occured while going to accoutnt page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer, session, registration, marketplace

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: objectManagerInterface in /var/www/html/htg/htg/app/code/Webkul/MpBlog/Block/Account/Navigation.php on line 139

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: objectManagerInterface in /var/www/html/htg/htg/app/code/Webkul/MpBlog/Block/Account/Navigation.php on line 139

```
#1 Webkul\MpBlog\Block\Account\Navigation->__construct(&Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context#000000000ee5ae0e0000000025304675#, &Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime#000000000ee5afbb0000000025304675#, &Magento\Customer\Model\Session\Interceptor#000000000ee5ae890000000025304675#, &Webkul\Marketplace\Model\ProductFactory#000000000ee5aaf00000000025304675#, &Webkul\Marketplace\Model\OrdersFactory#000000000ee5aaf30000000025304675#, &Webkul\Marketplace\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory#000000000ee5aaf20000000025304675#, &Webkul\Marketplace\Model\SellertransactionFactory#000000000ee5aaf50000000025304675#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory#000000000ee5af2f0000000025304675#, &Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory#000000000ee5afe30000000025304675#, &Webkul\Marketplace\Model\SaleslistFactory#000000000ee5aaf40000000025304675#, &Magento\Shipping\Model\Config#000000000ee5aaf10000000025304675#, &Magento\Payment\Model\Config#000000000ee5aafc0000000025304675#, &Webkul\Marketplace\Helper\Data\Interceptor#000000000ee5a8de0000000025304675#, &Webkul\MpBlog\Helper\Data#000000000ee5aa820000000025304675#, array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Webkul\MpBlog\Bl...', array(&Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context#000000000ee5ae0e0000000025304675#, &Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime#000000000ee5afbb0000000025304675#, &Magento\Customer\Model\Session\Interceptor#000000000ee5ae890000000025304675#, &Webkul\Marketplace\Model\ProductFactory#000000000ee5aaf00000000025304675#, &Webkul\Marketplace\Model\OrdersFactory#000000000ee5aaf30000000025304675#, &Webkul\Marketplace\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory#000000000ee5aaf20000000025304675#, &Webkul\Marketplace\Model\SellertransactionFactory#000000000ee5aaf50000000025304675#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory#000000000ee5af2f0000000025304675#, &Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory#000000000ee5afe30000000025304675#, &Webkul\Marketplace\Model\SaleslistFactory#000000000ee5aaf40000000025304675#, &Magento\Shipping\Model\Config#000000000ee5aaf10000000025304675#, &Magento\Payment\Model\Config#000000000ee5aafc0000000025304675#, &Webkul\Marketplace\Helper\Data\Interceptor#000000000ee5a8de0000000025304675#, &Webkul\MpBlog\Helper\Data#000000000ee5aa820000000025304675#, array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Webkul\MpBlog\Bl...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Webkul\MpBlog\Bl...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/BlockFactory.php:46]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory->createBlock('Webkul\MpBlog\Bl...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:272]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance('Webkul\MpBlog\Bl...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:252]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock('Webkul\MpBlog\Bl...', 'seller_mpblog', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:229]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ScheduledStructure#000000000ee5a94c0000000025304675#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure#000000000ee5ada60000000025304675#, 'seller_mpblog') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:134]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context#000000000ee5a96e0000000025304675#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context#000000000ee5a97c0000000025304675#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:81]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context#000000000ee5a96e0000000025304675#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context#000000000ee5a97c0000000025304675#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:352]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('generateElements', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('generateElements', array(), array(array('layout-model-cac...', 'core-session-dep...', 'customer-session...', 'catalog-session-...', 'persistent-sessi...', 'checkout-session...', 'tax-session-depe...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:91]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:55]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:224]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:237]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:242]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000000ee5ac800000000025304675#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000000ee5ac800000000025304675#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000000ee5ac800000000025304675#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000000ee5ac800000000025304675#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000000ee5ac800000000025304675#), array(array('result-messages', 'result-builtin-c...', 'result-varnish-c...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:130]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000000ee5ac800000000025304675#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:120]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000000ee5ac9b0000000025304675#) called at [index.php:39]
```

Comment: is this an exception that occurs every time a customer tries to register? or more of an event that happens from time to time?

Comment: Please update your question with code on line 67 in given file.

Comment: if (strpos($currentUrl, $coll['controller_path']) !== false) {
                        $url = $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl("marketplace/account/login");
                    }

Comment: @ Diana Botan Yes everytime when add customer and selection option seller yes

Answer (score 0):

If a needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character. This behavior is deprecated as of `PHP 7.3.0`, and relying on it is highly discouraged.

To resolve this issue you need to switch to `PHP 7.2` if you are currently in `PHP 7.3`

`Magento 2.3.5-p1` and below has an issue with `PHP 7.3`

**#Edited:**

If your magento version is greater than `2.3.5` then the module you have used **Webkul_Marketplace** is probably for older version of magento

Comment: But my magento varsion is 2.3.6

Comment: Please see updated answer

Comment: I have checked that Webkul_Marketplace version should be lower than magento version. My Webkul_Marketplace version is 2.3.0 and magento version is 2.3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Try with cast the needle value to string in **strpos** function on given line using **strval()** function.

For example,

```
strpos($haystack,strval($needel));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here:

1. You contact the module's development team and ask for a fix.
2. You install a debugger(eg. Xdebug) and place breakpoints and go down the code stack trace to identify which is the problem.